# How to resolve my Open Atrium installation error?

Tags: installation, distributions

I am very new to open atrium.  I installed [Open Atrium](https://www.drupal.org/project/openatrium) and now the home page is not loading properly. Instead I have the following error:

> Warning: file_put_contents(temporary://fil29F1.tmp): failed to open
>   stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in
>   file_unmanaged_save_data() (line 1936 of
>   C:\wamp\www\openatrium\includes\file.inc). The file could not be
>   created.

Comment: Check for permissions related errors at `/admin/reports/status` and make sure your permissions are set properly for your `/tmp` and `/sites/default/files/*` directories.

Comment: Please indicate how I can check the the reports because the openatrium home page does not load. what permissions should be on the sites/default/files directories?

Comment: Warning: file_put_contents(temporary://fil4AAC.tmp): failed to open stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in file_unmanaged_save_data() (line 1936 of C:\wamp\www\openatrium\includes\file.inc).
The file could not be created.  What does the above error mean?

Comment: @NicoleCox it means it could not save a file. Based on `DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper`, I'm going to guess an issue writing to the temp folder like @PatrickRyan said. If you can't use the current folder, check @D.vasanth Kumar's answer on how to change it via the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

open -> admin/config/media/file-system

Change Temporary directory -> sites/default/files

[image]

Comment: This is a bad idea if you have any private files as it means temporary copies of them that may not have been deleted yet will be publicly accessible. The temporary file area should be outside your webroot OR at the very least in a folder that's protected by .htaccess or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, if this where to happen during installation, is adding,

```
$conf['file_temporary_path'] = 'sites/all/files/tmp'
```

To the `settings.php` file and making sure that the folder exists and the permissions are correct.

This is assuming that you can't use `/tmp` for some reason.